# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a shopping cart with laravel and am having trouble with one of the methods

this is the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pedidos__produtos.pedidos_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select id_produto, sum(total) as Total, count(1) as qtd from `pedidos__produtos` where `pedidos__produtos`.`pedidos_id` = 1 and `pedidos__produtos`.`pedidos_id` is not null group by `id_produto` order by `id_produto` desc)

I searched the entire code, but I did not refer this field "pedidos_id" anywhere
This error happens when I call "$pedidos[0]->pedido_produtos," in Carrinhocontroller.php

These are the related methods and migrations:

CarrinhoController.php

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Pedidos;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class CarrinhoController extends Controller
 {
    function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index(){

    $pedidos = Pedidos::where([
        'id_user' => Auth::id()
    ])->get();

    dd([
        $pedidos,
        $pedidos[0]->pedido_produtos,
        //$pedidos[0]->pedidos_produtos[0]->produto
    ]);
    return view('carrinho.index', compact('pedidos'));

 }
}
```

Pedidos.php

```
<?php

 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Pedidos extends Model
 {
    public function pedido_produtos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pedidos_Produtos')
    ->select( \DB::raw('id_produto, sum(total) as Total, count(1) as qtd'))
    ->groupBy('id_produto')
    ->orderBy('id_produto', 'desc');
 }
}
```

Pedidos_Produtos.php

```
<?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Pedidos_Produtos extends Model
   {
     public function produto(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Produtos', 'id_produto', 'id');
     }
 }
```

Migration from Pedidos:

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class CreatePedidosTable extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pedidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('pedidos');
 }
}
```

and from pedidos_produtos

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class CreatePedidosProdutosTable extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pedidos__produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('id_pedido')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_produto')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('total', 6, 2)->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('id_pedido')->references('id')->on('pedidos');
        $table->foreign('id_produto')->references('id')->on('produtos');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('pedidos__produtos');
 }
}
```

Can Anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generates automatically if foreignKey attribute is not defined on `hasMany` method.
it generates field name from `classname_id` pattern. Also localKey default value is class PK.

```
public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
```

You can use like this.

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\Pedidos_Produtos','id_pedido')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is probably to do with this line:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Pedidos_Produtos')
```

If you do not explicitly tell Laravel what the IDs are called on each table when defining a hasMany relationship, it will assume that the id is `{table_name}_id` which is where the `pedidos_id` is coming from.

Try adding the foreign and local keys to the hasMany, something like this:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Pedidos_Produtos', 'id_pedido', 'id')
```